# IIS 8.5 Request Filtering block referrer spam traffic

Tags: iis-8.5, spam-filter, request-filtering

Recently I'm having a lot of requests that I see in google analytics from these domains (+25 others...):

```
scanner-irvin.top
scanner-viktor.top
compliance-alex.top
scanner-ivan.top
scanner-jess.top
scanner-julia.top
scanner-walt.top
scanner-elena.top
scanner-Jessica.top
```

But I don't know how to block these requests via Request Filtering in IIS 8.5.
Via a Deny Sequence for example the keyword "bad" can be added and if "bad" appears in the url of your own site it will block it I suppose, but how to block the hosts?

The samples on the IIS website are from older versions or not that detailed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't block so called "ghost referrals", that you see in Google Analytics, on your web server. The traffic never reaches your site. See https://moz.com/blog/stop-ghost-spam-in-google-analytics-with-one-filter for a detailed explanation.